# Including multiple dataset transformers in custom transformer

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

Here is my custom transformer, meant to transform the subject dataframe of encoding and scaling:

```
class DfGrooming(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.encodable_columns = ['Education','EmploymentType','MaritalStatus', 'HasMortgage', 'HasDependents', 'LoanPurpose', 'HasCoSigner']
        self.scalable_columns = ['Age', 'Income', 'LoanAmount', 'CreditScore', 'MonthsEmployed', 'InterestRate', 'LoanTerm']
        self.encoder = LabelEncoder()
        self.scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,5))
        self.X_encoded = pd.DataFrame()
        self.X_scaled = pd.DataFrame()
    
def fit(self, X, y=None):
    self.encoder.fit(X[self.encodable_columns])
    self.scaler.fit(X[self.scalable_columns])
    return self

def transform(self, X, y=None):
    self.X_encoded = self.encoder.transform(X[self.encodable_columns])
    print(self.X_encoded.shape)
    X.drop(columns=self.encodable_columns, axis=1, inplace=True)
    X = pd.concat([X, self.X_encoded], axis=1)
    print(X.shape)
    self.X_scaled = X.filter(self.scalable_columns, axis=1)
    self.X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(self.X_scaled))
    self.X_scaled.columns = self.scalable_columns
    X[self.scalable_columns] = self.X_scaled[self.scalable_columns]
    X.drop(['LoanID'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    print(X.shape)
    
    return X
```

But after running the pipeline:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([('preparer', DfGrooming())])
t = pipeline.fit_transform(train_df)
t.head()
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: bad input shape (178742, 7)
```

I would like to know what is actually happening and if I am missing anything in this implementation of transformers. Also please suggest better ways to implement this procedure. Thank you

I tried to include 2 transformers in one custom transformer.
I was expecting to combine 2 steps (and possibly 4 - removing and adding the encoded and scaled columns into the main dataframe)

I have a working algorithm where I semi-automatically transform the Validation and Test sets with functions, but wanted to try pipelines

Comment: Always provide the full error traceback, and preferably a sample dataset that we can reproduce the error with.

Comment: You may want to consider using a `ColumnTransformer` instead of a custom class.

Comment: ColumnTransformer was what I was looking for, thank you!